# Double script tags for route requested in SSR

Tags: reactjs, webpack, chunking, isomorphic, server-side-rendering

I've my SSR repo(inferno-react like lib) bundled using `webpack`. It has 2 route files, 1 for server and 1 for client, exactly same but chunking is happening at client side using require.ensure. 
One of the route looks like this:

```
<Route path="/home" getComponent={(props, cb) => {      
  require.ensure([], require => cb(null, 
  require('../views/containers/Home').default), 'home');
}}/>
```

Meaning, when browser will be parsing `.html` and `bundle.js` is downloaded on the browser, webpack will **then** insert that chunked route's component's `.js`script tag into html and **then** it will be downloaded. But that slows it a little bit as that route's `.js` is downloaded only after `bundle.js` is downloaded... So, I'm manually adding script tag from server for whatever requested chunk route dynamically with help of `webpack-manifest-plugin`.  But, now, for every requested route, I've double script tags in the `.html` file for that chunked component. One due to manually adding on server and one when we create chunk in webpack using `require.ensure`.

Things work but fine 2 script tags! :/

Is there a way I can avoid it Or how else can I handle it while keeping the chunking at client side.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to load the chunk asynchronously, then I would drop `require.ensure` and simply use `require`, so that the code is included in your main bundle.  Then you don't need any of the script tags except for the main bundle inclusion.

Otherwise, if you want chunking in order to separate code for different pages, then use a second entry point instead of auto-generated chunks.

Comment: Chunking is needed, hence was added. Yeah, multiple point entry is straightforward solution and certainly would resolve issue but that's what I'm trying to avoid because addition of each new route will lead to change in addition/removal in webpack which I was thinking to avoid.

Comment: Using named chunks, can you not use only the static script tag (e.g. insert in html manually), instead of inserting using the manifest plugin?  Or is this required because of using cachebuster hashes in the bundle names?  I admit to some confusion about what you're doing on the server here.

Comment: It may appear to be, but it is nothing to do with cachebusting, I just want exact file name. Purpose is only for it to not wait for bundle.js to load before my chunk is requested.. To give you more info, my server route is like, `<Route path="/home" component={ Home } filename="home.js"/>` And when I get mapping as `home.js : home_hash.js` at build time using manifest plugin, I use `filename` props to get exact file name from that key-value mapping to insert actual file in script tag(defer and added after bundle.js script tag) in html for component(chunk) being requested.

Comment: The main advantage of having chunks is to load them as needed.  If you want to pre-load this code anyway, why have it as a chunk?  It sounds like you're worried about build time, if I understand you correctly?  If you want exact filename and don't worry about cache, then use `home.js` without the hash.  Not sure I can help, sorry!

Comment: Please read again! I never mentioned that all my chunk scripts are added in html all at once!!. Only that  script of chunk entry is added as script tag which is "currently" being requested from server. It's a performance gain on first-paint. And in SPA, it can "significantly" help. And again, my question is not to get exact file names. I want to simple write some code in `route.js` to tell that don't insert script tag for FIRST LOAD bcoz it can safely assume that server has already done it.

Comment: Well, I would still say to stop using `require.ensure` if you're loading the bundle yourself.  Just use `require`.    In any case, the second script tag shouldn't matter terribly; you should just hit the browser cache, no?

Comment: :D `require.ensure` is needed when client take over, buddy! I know about bundle loader. AFAIK, it does the same thing as inserting script tag.

Comment: I think we're not understanding each other well; sorry I couldn't help!